# The style of the application changes when I wrap components in a ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I'm getting acquainted with react-native and faced the following problem: when I add a ScrollView and put content in it, the style of the application changes. How can this issue be resolved?

Before adding the ScrollView:

[image]

After adding the ScrollView:

[image]

```
function Weather({ temp, city, condition, daily, hourly }) {
  return (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={weatherOptions[condition].gradient}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name={weatherOptions[condition].iconName}
            size={96}
            color="#fff"
          />
          <Text style={styles.text}>{city}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{temp}℃</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
          <WeatherDaily daily={daily} />
          <WeatherHourly hourly={hourly} />
          <DetailedDailyForecast />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </LinearGradient>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 28,
    color: "white",
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  topContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bottomContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview):

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes quick to debug.